# can I change launcher activity in MainAvtivity

Tags: android

How can I change Launcher activity in android studio using Button click in Java file??
for example, if user clicks Button1 then a activity will be launcher activity and if user clicks Button2 then another activity will be a launcher activity???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which activity is launched at startup is determined by the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you cannot modify this at runtime.

However, you can make an activity whose sole purpose is to launch the app and *then choose* which other activity to launch:

- in button 1 click, save activity 1's name into a sharedpreferences entry
- in button 2 click, save the other's name
- in the launch activity, check the value of the sharedpreferences entry and launch an intent with the correct activity based on that

**Edit**: example for what you are trying to do

In your Button1 click:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // get the sharedpreferences with the name "myPreferencesName"
    // and the mode "MODE_PRIVATE" (i.e. only you can read the settings stored in it)
    // and then get its editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().
      getSharedPreferences("myPreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
      edit();
    editor.putString("activityToLaunch", "activity1"); // activity1 can be whatever string you choose, not neccessarily the actual name of the activity
    editor.apply();
  }
});
```

In your button2 click, you do the same but put "activity2" as the preference value

In your MainActivity `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().
  getSharedPreferences("myPreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!prefs.contains("activityToLaunch")) {
  // neither button has been pressed since you installed the app
  // this always happens on the first launch after installation
  // do the editor thing here as you would in the button click
  // depending on which activity you want to be default, either set the preference value to "activity1", or "activity2", then editor.apply() it
}

if(prefs.getString("activityToLaunch").equals("activity1")) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
else {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: can you please give me any example ??

Comment: @MehrabHShuvo I added the example